# PHP Fastroute - Handle 404s

Tags: php, lumen, fastroute

In my application I'm using [FastRoute](https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute) and I would like to have different types of 404 responses:

- When a call is made to a **not existing** endpoint starting with `/api` then the application should return a **JSON** 404 response.
- When a call is made to a not existing endpoint then the application should return a generic 404.

To get a generic 404 response I did as per the documentation:

```php
$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        break;
```

But I'm having trouble finding a way to get a 404 JSON response in case of a not existing `/api` endpoint.
What I achieved so this:

```php
$router->addGroup('/api', function (RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->post('/login', 'ApiController@login');
    $r->addRoute('*', '[/{str}]', 'ApiController@notFound');
});
```

For example:

- when calling `/api/not-existing-endpoint` it returns a JSON 404 response (so it's OK).
- when calling `/api/not-existing-endpoint/aaa/bbb/ccc` it does not catch it and it returns a generic 404.

How can fix the pattern of the route `$r->addRoute('*', '[/{str}]', 'ApiController@notFound');` in order to also catch the nested URIs like `/api/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### use route path with regular expression.

```php
$r->addRoute('*', '[/{any:.*}]', 'ApiController@notFound');
```

###### My full code.

```php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$dispatcher = \FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello[/]', function() {
        echo 'hello';
    });
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello/{name}', function($attribute) {
        echo 'hello ' . $attribute['name'];
    });
    $r->addGroup('/api', function (\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
        $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello[/]', function() {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['msg' => 'hello API']);
        });
        $r->addRoute('*', '[/{any:.*}]', function() {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['msg' => 'not found']);
        });
    });
});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
// for dynamic subfolder. https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/issues/110
$base  = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
ltrim($base, '/') ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($base)) : '';
// end dynamic subfolder.
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        http_response_code(404);
        echo 'not found';
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        http_response_code(405);
        echo 'method not allowed';
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        // ... call $handler with $vars
        $handler($vars);
        break;
}
```

Tested:

- https://localhost/api => JSON 'not found'
- https://localhost/api/hello => JSON 'hello API'
- https://localhost/api/notfound => JSON 'not found'
- https://localhost/api/notfound/notfound => JSON 'not found'
- https://localhost/notfound => HTML 'not found'

#### Alternative

I would recommend you to use 404 route to handle this instead. It is better and easier to manage your code in the future because it will not mixed with **normal route**.

```php
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        http_response_code(404);
        $expUri = explode('/', $uri);
        if ($expUri[1] === 'api') {
            // if first url segment is api. please check this again in your application that it is [1] or [0] and correct it.
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['msg' => 'not found']);
        } else {
            echo 'not found';
        }
        break;
    // ...
}
```

###### My full code.

```php
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';


$dispatcher = \FastRoute\simpleDispatcher(function(\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello[/]', function() {
        echo 'hello';
    });
    $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello/{name}', function($attribute) {
        echo 'hello ' . $attribute['name'];
    });
    $r->addGroup('/api', function (\FastRoute\RouteCollector $r) {
        $r->addRoute('GET', '/hello[/]', function() {
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['msg' => 'hello API']);
        });
    });
});

// Fetch method and URI from somewhere
// for dynamic subfolder. https://github.com/nikic/FastRoute/issues/110
$base  = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
ltrim($base, '/') ? $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], strlen($base)) : '';
// end dynamic subfolder.
$httpMethod = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
$uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

// Strip query string (?foo=bar) and decode URI
if (false !== $pos = strpos($uri, '?')) {
    $uri = substr($uri, 0, $pos);
}
$uri = rawurldecode($uri);

$routeInfo = $dispatcher->dispatch($httpMethod, $uri);
switch ($routeInfo[0]) {
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::NOT_FOUND:
        // ... 404 Not Found
        http_response_code(404);
        $expUri = explode('/', $uri);
        if ($expUri[1] === 'api') {
            // if first url segment is api. please check this again in your application that it is [1] or [0] and correct it.
            header('Content-type: application/json');
            echo json_encode(['msg' => 'not found']);
        } else {
            echo 'not found';
        }
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED:
        $allowedMethods = $routeInfo[1];
        // ... 405 Method Not Allowed
        http_response_code(405);
        echo 'method not allowed';
        break;
    case FastRoute\Dispatcher::FOUND:
        $handler = $routeInfo[1];
        $vars = $routeInfo[2];
        // ... call $handler with $vars
        $handler($vars);
        break;
}
```

Comment: The first solution `[/{any:.*}]` is the more suitable for me. Thanks a lot!